# Why is `grep "^ *[^<]" <somefile.xml` giving unexpected results

Tags: linux, bash, grep, xml

Say I have a file containing some xml like so:

```
<headtag>
  <firsttag>a string</firsttag>
  <secondtag>a string</secondtag>
  <subleveltag>
    a line with no tag
  </subleveltag>
</headtag>
```

I want to be able to grep any line with no opening tag (or no preceding `<` to be more specific) at the beginning.

I've found that:

```
grep -v "^ *<" <somefile.xml
```

works as expected:

```
a line with no tag
```

However, when I try:

```
grep "^ *[^<]" <somefile.xml
```

This appears to me to "grab a line beginning with zero or more spaces excluding those immediately followed by `<`. However I get this instead:

```
  <firsttag>a string</firsttag>
  <secondtag>a string</secondtag>
  <subleveltag>
    a line with no tag
  </subleveltag>
```

Why doens't this work the way I'm expecting?

NOTE: I'm *not* trying to parse the xml in this way. I am well aware that I shouldn't be parsing xml using grep.

I'm running GNU bash 4.2.46(2), GNU grep 2.20, on RHEL 7something.

Comment: `"^ *[^<]"` would indeed match two spaces a the beginning of a line, since a space is not `<` - perhaps `"^ *[^ <]"`

Comment: Yep that makes sense. I was pretty sure it would be something simple that I missed.

Comment: Note that unless you are confining yourself to very simple stuff, regex is not sufficient for parsing XML based expressive languages like XML, HTML, or just about any other *ML. Using a parser/locator for XML is recommended. for instance your prettified XML will match your pattern, but if the same XML is minified, your pattern will no longer work.

Comment: @FrankThomas Thanks yeah I was hoping for something simple, quick and dirty. It's proving to be maybe a little too dirty. Probably should've just gone for ElementTree in the first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This pattern is tricking you:

```
grep "^ *[^<]" <somefile.xml
```

The regex pattern means:

`^ *`  "There may be one or more leading spaces, but a space is not required."

`[^<]` "Match any character that is not a `<`.
=> This also matches a space character.

*As `^ *` may be the empty string, any line not starting with a `<` will match.*

In your sample using prettyfied XML `[^<]` matches

1. The `a` in the line without a `<`.
2. The last of the leading spaces in the lines with a `<`.

So only the first and the last line, with a `<` as the first character, are omitted. This is the result you describe.

---

To get all lines not starting with a `<` (ignoring leading spaces) this should work:

```
grep "^ *[^< ]" somefile.xml
```

Please note the added space character in the negated pattern group.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seems really obvious now. I think I just needed another coffee.

Answer (score 1):

> Why doens't this work the way I'm expecting?

Using the **first line** matched incorrectly from your example:

> <firsttag>a string</firsttag>

Let's breakdown the matching of `grep "^ *[^<]"`.  The use of `^` anchors the search to match any line beginning with  `*[^<]`.  There are two leading whitespaces in the **first line** which are each matched.  The **first match** is the first ' ' with `^ *` and the **second match** is the second ' ' with `[^<]`. Therefore, the entire line is matched.  This is the reason the other unwanted lines are matched also.

Using `^ *[^< ]` instead, the **second match** with the whitespace is prevented, since `[^< ]` excludes both '<' and ' ' characters.  So, a matched line must begin with at least one character that is neither '<' or ' '.